# SoapUI Service mocking - How to transfer values between mock responses?

Tags: properties, scope, mocking, soapui

Is there a way to transfer values generated by groovy script in mockResponse1 context to project scope property. Then I would like to use this value in another scripted mockResponse2?
I can transfer values from Request1 to Request2 (client side). Can't seem to figure how to do it for mockResponses (server side).

Model:
mockResponse1.someVar -> project.Property -> mockResponse2.someOtherVar

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This works from a mockResponse script:

```
// get project scoped property
def a = mockResponse.mockOperation.mockService.project.getPropertyValue("someProjectProperty")
// set project scoped property
mockResponse.mockOperation.mockService.project.setPropertyValue("someProjectProperty", someVar)
```